# How to convert RGBA_8888 formatted image to opencv mat in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv, android-camerax

I am working on a android project where I need to use openCV for detecting and drawing over objects from live camera feed. But I don't know how can i convert to openCV mat format from [RGBA_8888](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) format which is my analyzer output image format.

Found questions about default camerax output format [YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888) to mat conversions but nothing about RGBA8888.

Comment: Can you just not change the camera analyzer output format back to the default YUV_420_888 format? As the native camera format for camera hardware is usually YUV_420_888 and changing it to RGBA8888 is a slower software conversion adding latency. Then you could use the answer you have already found.

Comment: @Andrew YUV_420_888 to mat conversions that I saw  first converts to rgb, so I thought probably camerax internal RGBA conversion would be faster than these solutions.